# Check programmatically if glassfish is running in debug mode

Tags: glassfish

To provide special debug information I want to know if the glassfish server is running in debug mode. Is it possible to check the running mode programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GlassFish Server offers a REST API for management and monitoring.  You can connect to the DAS and parse the jvm options:

http://localhost:4848/management/domain/list-jvm-options.html

or:

http://localhost:4848/management/domain/list-jvm-options.json

or:

http://localhost:4848/management/domain/list-jvm-options.xml

Hope this helps!